# Set parts of listcolumn to NULL in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- rownames_to_column(mtcars,var = "car")
mtcars$id <- c(1:length(mtcars$car))
mtcars$make <- map_chr(mtcars$car,~strsplit(.x," ")[[1]][1])

mt2 <- mtcars %>% select(1:4,id,make) %>% nest(-make,.key = "l")
mt4 <- mt2[1:5,]
mt5 <- mt2[1:5,]
```

`

Now - I´d like to have the listcolumn for mazda set to NULL.

```
 mt4[mt4$make=="Mazda","l"]<-NULL
```

However, comparing `mt4$l` to `mt5$l` I find that the "mazda" elements have been removed, but that the other elements have been shifted upward. 
Could someone explain why this is logical?
How can I selectively only NULL a certain element within a listcolumn?

Comment: Always include non-base packages in your sample code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include non-base packages in your questions. In this case, we need:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
```

(or just `library(tidyverse)`, I believe).

By assigning `NULL` like that to an element, you are telling R to *remove that element from the list*, thereby making it shorter. If you want to replace the element with a `NULL` element, try

```
mt4[mt4$make=="Mazda","l"] <- list(list(NULL))
```

instead. (This happens to also work if the conditional `mt4$make=="Mazda"` were to return multiple matches; obviously not a factor with this example, but good to know.)

Comment: A complementary example: Try `mtcars[1, 1] <- NULL`, you get `Error: replacement has length zero`

Comment: And thanks for providing the individual packages - I like not having to attach *everything*.

Comment: Thx. I still dont quite grasp the list(list()) - could you please explain why the double list is necessary.

Comment: `mt4[...]` is still a `list`, even if it is length 1. As such, if the length of the left is equal to the length of the right (`length(list(NULL))` is 1), then it does a one-for-one replacement *with the contents*, which in this case is equivalent to `<- NULL`. By double-`list`ing it, it ensures that each element to be replaced is replaced with a `list` that just so happens to contain `NULL`. It seems like some crazy mojo, I agree. When dealing with this type of obscurity, I often have to resort to trial-and-error to ensure it works for "0 or more" matches.